# RTC 1307 when connected to a relay via Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino-nano

I was posting a question but to be completely sure i did some more tweaking in the code and solved at least functionally my problem.

I decided to post it anyway to have suggestions for a better solution and / or help whoever has the same problem.

The project is a flowers watering application.
I set up an RTC connected with Arduino Nano using LEDs to simulate the operations, it works really well, no mistakes when RTC.readTime requests.

Once satisfied I replaced the LED with a relay to be connected to the pump, and then the problem appeared:

Randomly the reading is not correct, something like (YYYY/MM/DD H:M:S) represented as 165/0/165 0:165:0. 
The combinations of 165 and 0s are completely random but only 165 and 0s are present.

My solution was to check after each reading if there was any 165s into the returned data, and if yes, read the time again. This was the medicine.
This mistake appears only and always when i replace the LED with a relay, with or without connected charge.

Circuitry is very simple as well as is the code.

```c
  RTC.readTime();
  if (RTC.h == 165 || 
      RTC.m == 165 || 
      RTC.s == 165 ||
      RTC.dd == 165 ||
      RTC.mm == 165 ||
      RTC.yyyy == 165 ) {
        RTC.readTime();
        Serial.print("Mistake found in step N. ");
        Serial.println(countCycles);
  }

  countCycles ++;
```

From the printout I can confirm that the mistake is absolutely random but never immediately subsequent to another mistake.
Any clues?
Thank you for any comments

Comment: Did you use a relay or a all-in-one relay module/breakout? A relay itself requires some additional components to connect it to an Arduino. They also require quite a bit of current, which can cause a short voltage drop, which some components don't like. Turning a relay off can cause some back EMF, which some components don't like. Adding a large capacitor might be enough to fix these issues.

Comment: Hi Gerben, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Answer to your question first: I used a Relay module from Elegoo that as said does not need any other components to be connected with Arduino, nevertheless i believe that a condenser will not do any harm. Which capacity do you think suitable? and where to fit it? my electronic skill is quite low 'cause i am more a SW guy beginning to play with Arduino for fun while retired. I dont know where to put a picture here, otherwise i may have posted a picture of the module. Ciao

Comment: Just forgot to say that i powered the circuit with a proper source with load of current available.

Comment: I'd try a 10-100 uF (electrolytic) capacitor near the module. It might be that your power-supply can't handle the very sudden increase in current fast enough. I too came from a SW background. When things start to act weird, it's mostly a power issue, I've learned.

Comment: Do you mean between + and - on the power supply?  An update on the mistakes is that they appear in sequence as well so i had to set a do - while loop.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I should have mentioned that. Between + and - (Vcc and GND).